# Return more than one result from a function

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, count, roles

This is my script which lists all the roles...

```
function all_the__roles() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
    $roles = '';
    $role_count = '';
    foreach($the_roles as $role) {
        $roles .= $role . '<br />';
        $role_count++;
    }
    return $roles;
}

echo all_the__roles();
```

If I change `return $roles;` to `return $role_count;` then I get the number of roles.

Is there a way I can have both without writing an additional separate function? I want to list the roles **and** also the number roles. So the output could be something like:

```
Administrator
Editor
Client
3
```

Cheers.

Comment: personally I wouldn't bother with a function for this you can do `$the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();`  and then do `implode('<br>', $the_roles )` or `count($the_roles)` etc.  And then there is no reason making a function for it.  Otherwise do `return ['roles' => implode('<br>', $the_roles ), 'count' => count($the_roles)]`  and remove the `foreach` -6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
function all_the__roles() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
    $roles = '';
    $role_count = 0;
    foreach($the_roles as $role) {
        $roles .= $role . '<br />';
        $role_count++;
    }

    if($role_count > 0){
        $roles .= $role_count . '<br />';
    }

    return $roles;
}

echo all_the__roles();
```

Comment: That works, but it's not exactly what I need. I probably could have explained it better. Somewhere in the document I might want to list the roles, and somewhere else in the document I might want to display the number of roles. So I need the function to offer me a way to do either in any part of the document.

Comment: yes try this one

function all_the__roles() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
    
    $role_count = 0;
    $data = array();
    
    foreach($the_roles as $role) {
        $data['roles'][] = $role;
        $role_count++;
    }

    if($role_count > 0){
        $data['roles'] = $role_count;
    }

    return $data;
}

print_r(all_the__roles());

Comment: all they need is this `function all_the__roles() { global $wp_roles; $the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names(); return ['roles' => implode('<br>', $the_roles ), 'count' => count($the_roles)]; }`

Comment: function all_the__roles() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $the_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
    
    $role_count = 0;
    $data = array();
    
    foreach($the_roles as $role) {
        $data['roles'][] = $role;
        $role_count++;
    }

    if($role_count > 0){
        $data['roles_count'] = $role_count;
    }

    return $data;
}

$roles_data =  all_the__roles();

$roles = $roles_data['roles']; // or
$roles = implode("<br>",$roles);

$roles_count = $roles_data['roles_count'];